# Importing an html page in a div and executing "body onload"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a HTML/JS newbie.

I have an HTML page "B.html" with:

```html
    <body onload="init()" >
    -----other html/js stuffs
```

that is loaded fine in browser.

I include B.html inside a div in "A.html" (tab) using:

```html
<ul class="tab">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openTab(event, 'Main')">Main</a></li> 
.........
</ul>

<div id="Main" class="tabcontent"> </div>
.........

<script>
$(function(){ $("#Main").load("B.html"); });

function openTab(evt, tabName) {
.........
</script>
```

`openTab` function manage tab selections activating appropriate `div`

Now, opening B.html all things work fine.

Embedding B.html inside A.html as I wrote before, works except for js function that need to be initialized by "init". I cannot obviously use `body onload="init()"` because I'm already inside body of A.html

How I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the init function in the callback function of the load:

```
$("#Main").load("B.html", function() {
    init();
});
```

The callback function is fired after the load has completed

More information about [`.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)